# D3 cross tabulation HTML table

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to create a D3 cross tabulation HTML table (there will be more interactive features, this is just the first step) based on JSON data.  I can populate the horizontal table header, but am having trouble with the vertical headers and data fields.

The table should look something like the following:

[image: Cross tab]

My code so far ([JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/9xefktc2/)) is:

```
var nested = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d._id.env; })
    .entries(data.result);

console.log(nested);   

var table = d3.select("#table")
    .append("table")
    .style("border-collapse", "collapse")
    .style("border", "2px black solid");

var thead = table.append("thead");

thead.append("tr")
    .selectAll("th")
    .data(nested)
  .enter().append("th")
    .text(function(d) { return d.key; });

var tbody = table.append("tbody");


var tr = tbody.selectAll("tr")
    .data(nested.values)            // not sure how to get this
  .enter().append("tr");

tr.selectAll("td")
    .data(function(d) { console.log(d); return d; })
  .enter().append("td")
    .text(function(d, i) { console.log(d[i]); return d; });
```

The raw data is in the following format:

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "month" : 5,
                                "day" : 6,
                                "year" : 2014,
                                "env" : "A"
                        },
                        "ruleScore" : 83.25,
                        "jsPerPage" : 12,
                        "cssPerPage" : 4,
                        "imagesPerPage" : 7.75
                },
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "month" : 5,
                                "day" : 6,
                                "year" : 2014,
                                "env" : "B"
                        },
                        "ruleScore" : 83,
                        "jsPerPage" : 12,
                        "cssPerPage" : 4,
                        "imagesPerPage" : 10
                },
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "month" : 5,
                                "day" : 6,
                                "year" : 2014,
                                "env" : "C"
                        },
                        "ruleScore" : 83,
                        "jsPerPage" : 12,
                        "cssPerPage" : 5,
                        "imagesPerPage" : 10,
                },
                {
                        "_id" : {
                                "month" : 5,
                                "day" : 6,
                                "year" : 2014,
                                "env" : "D"
                        },
                        "ruleScore" : 83.08333333333333,
                        "jsPerPage" : 12,
                        "cssPerPage" : 6,
                        "imagesPerPage" : 9.25
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

I'm guessing this is pretty simple, just can't get my head around it - thanks!

Comment: [This tutorial](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/) may help.

Comment: Tutorial was helpful, but I'm still stuck on how to access the elements under the values in the nested data structure...still working on it though.  Thinking I might need to change the data structure itself.